# Proof that RLC networks are linear?

Tags: passive-networks, linear

I've been learning about RLC networks, superposition, two-port circuits etc. and a lot of derivations and equations implicitly assume the fact that the circuits in question are linear, no matter the weird and wonderful arrangements of the resistors, inductors and capacitors.

This sort of makes sense to me intuitively, but is there any proof (or any way to prove) that all RLC passive networks (except exceptions such as with non-ideal components) behave linearly?

Comment: All linear networks behave linearly. Define 'passive'. Do you consider a diode passive? Or ideal? All networks behave linearly except those that don't.

Comment: I've edited my question. I am specifically referring to RLC networks, with any combination of resistors, inductors and capacitors, and I want proof that these combinations will always react linearly

Comment: What about things like filament lamps? They have a strong temperature coefficient of resistance, so are non-linear, and passive. Actually, all resistors have a tempco, but some tempcos are bigger than others. Which means all practical resistors are non-linear, but most are very very close to linear, certainly those that you buy as 'resistors'. You haven't defined your permitted components properly yet. If you restrict the network to using linear components, then the question is a tautology. Do you mean 'do networks of linear components behave linearly?' ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're on about. I clearly specified ideal resistors, capacitors and inductors. Those that, in isolation, behave linearly.

Comment: So your question is 'will a network of LINEAR components behave linearly', not PASSIVE components, or IDEAL components. That's a tautology. No point in even asking the question. Component behaviour combines into a network by means of the linear operations of addition, multiplication by constants, integration and differentiation, which can only have a linear result.

Comment: I'm asking the question because I wanted proof of the math behind the combination of these components. No need to be rude - what may be obvious to you may not be obvious to others ;)

Comment: In reality, nothing behaves linearly so no, there can be no proof.

Comment: You can't prove a tautology, it just is. Linearity means 'obeys superposition'. It's the definition of it. You might as well ask for proof that 2==2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a resistor, inductor and capacitor there is a linear relationship between voltage and current.

**For a resistor:** \$ V_R=RI\$

**For an inductor:** \$V_L=Z_LI=j\omega L\cdot I \$

**For a capacitor:** \$V_C=Z_CI= \frac{1}{j\omega C}\cdot I \$

As you can see, the voltage across the various components is **proportional** to the current flowing through it, with the proportional constant being either \$R, \: j\omega L \$ or \$\frac{1}{j\omega C} \$.

Hence, any combination of a resistor, inductor and capacitor will also result in a linear relationship between voltage and current. So the entire system is linear.

Comment: Is the reason combinations are also linear because the formula where you combine impedances is also linear? E.g. impedances in series and parallel?

Comment: @GaryAllen The reason for linearity is because the voltage is always proportional to the current no matter what combination of impedances you make. You will never arrive at an expression like \$V=RI^2\$, you will always arrive at a linear term.

Answer (score 2):

> > there any proof (or any way to prove) that all RLC passive networks (except exceptions such as with non-ideal components) behave linearly?

Yes , Let's say a complex circuit of N- meshes having R,L,C elements(**with no initial conditions**), then you can always write mesh equation for each mesh and you'll get N  integro -differential equation which on differentiation gives you a **linear constant cofficient   differential equation** , so now you have N variables and N differential equation , and by substitution method,  you can always get a unique linear constant cofficient differential equation with desired input output variables .

And hence, we can say that no matter how complex R,L,C circuit is you'll always get a LCCDE between input and  output ,which is certainly a linear relation .

Comment: Before I accept as solved, just a question. The mesh equations that you have will contain complex impedances and and mesh currents. Where would the derivatives come into play? Why would you differentiate these equations?

Comment: @Gary Allen  Derivative and integration due to these relation - $$V= Ldi/dt , V= \frac{\int idt }{C}$$ and to remove this integration we have to differentiate one more time on both sides.